# How to use the .format right here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new in python and i having trouble with this problem here
Assuming that the population of a country A is 80 thousand inhabitants with an annual
of constant growth of 3% and that the population of B is 50 thousand inhabitants with a rate of
growth not yet known. 
Make a program that reads the estimated population growth rate
of city B and, based on the rate of growth read, your program should:

- Check that, with the reported growth rate, the population of city B
  will exceed the population of city A;
- If the population of city B is not exceeded, your program should
  print "The population of B will overcome. "
- If the population of city B exceeds, your program should print "The
  population of city B will exceed X years. ", where X must be replaced
  by the number of years in which the population B will exceed that of
  city A.

Growth rate will be made available as a float greater than 0, which represents the percentage of
growth of city B.

```
a = 80000
b = 50000

an = 0
while b <= a:

  a = a*0.03
  b = b*float(input())/100

  an += 1
  if a > b:            
    print("A populacão de B não vai ultrapassar")

  if b > a:        
    print("A populacão da cidade de B vai ultrapassar em'{} anos.".format(an))
```

The output that i would like to get is
X years to population B to surpass population A in this program where X would be substituted for the actual years that would take

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What goes wrong? what you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: my question is how can I print the amount of years that population B exceeds the population of A
The rest of the program seems to work fine except that part

Comment: Well it seems fine. Are you getting an error message? Does the output not what you expect? Please help us to help you

Comment: print(f"A populacão da cidade de B vai ultrapassar em'{an} anos."). Notice the " f" before the quote.

Comment: The output is not what i expect to get. The program prints 'em.1years' instead of the actual number of years that the population B would need to surpass population A

Comment: So the problem here is not with the printing... The problem is logical. Your program uses `input` from a user so that makes it alot harder to debug and help. You should give exact inputs with their expected outputs

Comment: For example. If the user inputs 5.0 i would like to print The city of city B will exceed in 25 years

Comment: 3 more notes @JoséFernando: if you want to calculate growth, you need to do `a = a*1.03` and `b = b * (1 + float(input())/100)`. Second, unless you want B's growth rate to be changing every year, you need to move the `input` before the `while` loop. Those 2 might affect your unwanted result. Lastly, you should consider moving the prints also outside the loop. This way, you get 25 prints if B passes after 25 years

Comment: @JoséFernando, I ran your code with those changes, with input 5.0 and the output was 25...

Comment: well, to update do you guys. I did it using a different logic... a = 80000
b = 50000
pcent_b = float(input())
for i in range(1, 101):
 a += (a/100)*3
 b += (b/100)*pcent_b
 if b > a:
  print("A população da cidade B vai ultrapassar em {} anos.".format(i))
  break
if a >= b:
 print("A população de B não vai ultrapassar."). 
I apologize for my English and for being relatively new to python and thank those who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

With fixed values for the a population and b population, an easy way of doing it would be.

```
a_population = 80000
b_population = 50000
A_GROWTH_RATE = 0.03
B_GROWTH_RATE = float(input()) / 100

if a_population > b_population and A_GROWTH_RATE >= B_GROWTH_RATE:
    print("A populacão de B não vai ultrapassar")
else:
    years = 0
    while b_population <= a_population:
        a_population += a_population * A_GROWTH_RATE
        b_population += b_population * B_GROWTH_RATE
        years += 1

    print("A populacão da cidade de B vai ultrapassar em'{} anos.".format(years))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, instead of using a loop, you can use a simple formula:

```py
import math

a = 80000
b = 50000
pcent_b = float(input())/100
a_growth = 1.03
b_growth = 1 + pcent_b

anos = math.ceil(math.log(b/a, a_growth/b_growth))

if anos > 0:
    print("A população da cidade B vai ultrapassar em {} anos.".format(anos)) 
else: 
    print("A população de B não vai ultrapassar.")
```